# Python/Scrapy: Extracting xpath from Ebay's dynamic description field

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm working on a project that is looking to ingest data from Ebay listings and store it for analysis.  I'm using Scrapy to scrape/crawl specific categories but I'm running into issues when trying to extract the text within an items' "description" field.  Each listing seems to have a unique layout for the description so I can't generalize an xPath for the item of my Scrapy object.

For example one advertisement may have a layout like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Primitive-Wall-Decor-Metal-Art-Butterfly-Rustic-Vintage-Style-Garden-Decor-/141693990060?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item20fd9eb4ac), while another may be formatted like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Rawlings-Football-St5-Official-Size-Full-Grain-Leather-Lot-Of-2-Previously-Used-/151727887062?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2353afd2d6).  How can I go about extracting the text within each description tab? I can successfully extract other fields, as their xPaths are universal in Ebay advertisements.  Here's the method I'm reffering to:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = EbayItem()
    item['url'] = response.url
    item['title'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="itemTitle"]/text()').extract()
    item['description']= response.xpath( #THISISWHEREIMLOST).extract()

    print ":("
```

Comment: Have you tried using ebay's web API? https://go.developer.ebay.com/what-ebay-api Not only would this eliminate the need for scraping, it would also help you make sure of their TOS. (Disclaimer: I haven't tried it.)

Comment: Ah I hadn't even considered if it violated their TOS, woops, turns out it does..

"you will not:
...
use any robot, spider, scraper or other automated means to access our Services for any purpose
..."
Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: You could always use regex instead of xpath.

Comment: you could use [crawlera](http://crawlera.com/) if you are worried about hitting the site (by its site, or even the api).